# Chart position at x=33000 value

Tags: c#, charts, double

I want to set the position of my chart at 33000. So it occurs an error because of 33000 > 32768.

How can I set this to `33000`?

```
chart2.Location = new Point(33000, 0);
```

Comment: What screen has 33k pixels? You're positioning the chart control, you're not setting the data of the chart.

Comment: I have 30 charts and I have to position these side by side. it works at at 30000px but now works at 33000 px.

Comment: yes. 32k is the limit. your screen has an even lower limit.. so if you really want to stick to the at best questionable idea you will need to do some paging..